# How to configure windows to show the custom icons in the UPnP iconList

Tags: windows, windows-7, upnp

Wen the Upnp device is configured with:

```
<iconList><icon>
     <mimetype>image/png</mimetype>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>45</height>
     <depth>32</depth>
     <url>/img/icon.png</url>
  </icon></iconList>
```

When windows 7 presents the device in the Windows Explorer Network window it does not use icon.png but a generic icon. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: What is the URL of your device description?

Answer (score 2):

Windows will always show its own icon, even if you made your custom icon available. Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153509/Advertise-your-Applications-Webinterface-on-the-Lo